# GCM pushnotification failing in IOS production environment with Internal Server error

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

My app stopped getting push notifications from last weekend. After proper debugging, it was found that GCM was failing with an error "NotRegistered".

```js
success: 0,
  failure: 1,
  canonical_ids: 0,
  results: [ { error: 'NotRegistered' } ] }
...
```

I have updated all my certificates and checked, only to get another new error.

```js
success: 0,
  failure: 1,
  canonical_ids: 0,
  results: [ { error: 'InternalServerError' } ] }
...
```

This is happening only with the IOS and the system is working flawlessly in android. I checked all the google forums, stack-overflow but got no where. Please help me out. TIA

Comment: I found a similar issue in the [Google Groups for Android GCM](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/78UezF2HBGM). The error `InternalServerError` might be an issue with your certificate. So they resolve this kind of issue by creating/uploading a new certificate. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a couple of threads in stack overflow and google groups on the same problem, but it was not clearly explained where to update the certificates (maybe I am a little amateur to understand it). All this time, I was updating the certificates in my app store and checked if it worked. I should also update my certificates in my GCM developers console. Once I did that, it worked like a charm.

Here is a detailed explanation I found that could be very much helpful for newbies like me ---> http://blog.airsource.co.uk/2016/01/29/quickstart-google-cloud-messaging-ios/